# What is the drawing style called that is used in the RSA Animate lectures?

Tags: drawing, style-identification

What is the drawing style called that is used in the RSA Animate lectures?

See some videos here: http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL39BF9545D740ECFF

I don't think they are standard caricatures, but I have seen similar styles elsewhere, but I can't remember where and I am not sure what to search on to see more of the style.

Comment: Just looks like standard pen and ink to me only on a whiteboard.

Comment: I'd call it 'cartooning'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RSA Animate videos are created by [CognativeMedia](http://www.cognitivemedia.co.uk/) using [ydraw](http://ydraw.com/).

This style of is often referred to as "animated vignettes" named after "[animated narrative vignette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animated_narrative_vignette)," an instructional technology used in education.

> An animated narrative vignette (ANV) is an instructional technology used to motivate and facilitate role-playing, problem solving, and discussion. Teachers develop the ANVs to present in class or in online training. Students might also create them in experiential learning exercises. They provide computer animation representations of teachable situations that encourage critical thinking and may also provide an instrument for assessing attitudes and behaviors. Vignettes have been used to teach mathematics and science, management skills, problem solving, and character education.

Answer (score 0):

As Krazer mentioned, one way of calling it is Animated narrative vignette (ANV).

Another way of calling it is [Whiteboard animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiteboard_animation).

> Whiteboard animation is the process of which an author physically
>   draws and records an illustrated story using a whiteboard- or
>   whiteboard like surface- and marker pens. The animations frequently
>   are aided with narration by script. The authors commonly use stop
>   motion animation to liven hand drawn illustrations, with YouTube used
>   as a common platform. It is also used in television and internet
>   advertisements to communicate to consumer's in a personal way. The
>   earliest videos made using Whiteboard Animation were published in 2009
>   on YouTube, used mostly for experimental purposes until developing
>   into a story telling device, focusing majority on narratives, though
>   it has many other uses in modern day.

[Here's](https://uxmastery.com/how-to-create-a-budget-whiteboard-animation/) a guideline on how to do a whiteboard animation.